# Searching for web-based Opensource software for accounting part of one holding Company

Tags: open-source, accounting

I am asking this question for finding some opensource software for one [holding company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holding_company) as its digital infrastructure of this company, this holding intends to provide services in 3 following fields:

1. Marketing
2. Accounting and finance
3. Providing specialized advice in the field

so i have googled the [**software for holding company**](https://www.google.com/search?q=software%20for%20holding%20company&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and, i found the accounting part of this company have many results, so i guess there is not any available software which covers all the 3 part of above list ( marketing and ...), and i have narrowed this question only about **accounting** part of this holding and if possible, I like to have some recommendation for the below question:

Finding the **web-based multilingual opensource accounting software** for one holding company.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks @Community, for your attempt to make this question clarified, i guess i have summarized the question at the end of its and asked one simple question which is : **trying to Find the web-based multilingual opensource accounting software for one holding company.**